# extract the log in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sh

HI I am new to shell script. I have a log file like this.

```
2018-01-18T15:55:15,637 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-37([])]: 
thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:OpenSession(317)) - Client 
protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V7
2018-01-18T15:55:15,648 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-37([])]: 
session.SessionState (SessionState.java:createPath(749)) - Created HDFS
```

I tried to filtered out the required columns like this.

```
cat hive-server2.log | grep 's3\|user\|query'

2018-01-18T16:20:39,464 WARN  [67272380-f3e9-40da-8e8e-a209c05eb4fe HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-37([])]: util.CurrentUserGroupInformation (CurrentUserGroupInformation.java:getGroupNameFromUser(52)) - user aa (auth:PROXY) via hive (auth:SIMPLE) has no primary groupName, setting groupName to be aa.
2018-01-18T16:23:25,389 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1735)) - Executing command(queryId=hive_20180118162325_5ad8be3f-80e7-468d-bb47-1bdc2d2fb624):      2018-01-18T16:23:25,393 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-63([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(2050)) - Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20180118162325_5ad8be3f-80e7-468d-bb47-1bdc2d2fb624); Time taken: 0.004 seconds
 2018-01-18T16:23:25,972 INFO  [67272380-f3e9-40da-8e8e-a209c05eb4fe HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-49([])]: s3n.S3NativeFileSystem (S3NativeFileSystem.java:open(1210)) - Opening 's3://f4340808-220a-424c-ba67-3f2383ea42ea-c000.csv' for reading
```

the above prints all the filtered keyword. Now I need to save like this.

IN .txt file

```
column names - TimeStamp,User,Query,file path
2018-01-18T16:23:25,972,select * from bv limit 5,Opening 
's3://aaaa' for reading
```

I don't know how to extract this column values in the above output. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1) your input log fragment does not contain neither `user` nor `query` keywords - post a testable fragment; 2) post the final expected result

Comment: I have updated the query.Kindly check it

Comment: elaborate what concrete substring is responsible for `S3 bucket path` field?

Comment: just s3 keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution for static log format:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "TimeStamp,User,Query,S3 bucket path" }
     /\<user\>/{ u=$10 }
     /Executing command\(queryId/{ sub(/.*queryId=[^[:space:]]+: /,""); q=$0 }
     /s3:\/\//{ print $1,u,q,$10 }' OFS=',' hive-server2.log
```

The output:

```
TimeStamp,User,Query,S3 bucket path
2018-01-18T16:23:25,972,a8197zz,select * from pfeevent limit 5,'s3://3m-his-dev-cayuga/Demo-Enterprise/TrustedZone/Published/Enrichment/Core/PFE/PFEEvent/part-00000-f4340808-220a-424c-ba67-3f2383ea42ea-c000.snappy.parquet'
```

Comment: @arunabimaniyu, that's why I wrote "for static log format". When you will describe and elaborate all the crucial lines format of your log file and make your conditions more clear - you'll increase your chances

Comment: TimeStamp,User,Query,S3 bucket path
,'s3://3m-his-dev-cayuga/Demo-Enterprise/TrustedZone/Published/Enrichment/Core/PFE/PFEEvent/part-00000-f4340808-220a-424c-ba67-3f2383ea42ea-c000.snappy.parquet'

Comment: whatever output u got.. that one also I am not getting..Whether I am making any mistake??

Comment: Humm any idea to how I get the required output ?

Comment: @arunabimaniyu, how can I guess if you have posted an arbitrary conditions

Comment: oops..I dont know. I am totally new to shell scripting.

Comment: Otherwise I can get the value one by one and finally I can concatenate.

Comment: @arunabimaniyu, ok, start with changing your question content and conditions to make them clear

Comment: pluse-uno for good answer (as usual) AND tech support ;-). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter, thanks. tech support is always much harder than givings answers. )